# Setting defaultRowPrefetch has no effect on query

Tags: spring, jdbc, oracle11g

I've got a weird issue with using Spring JDBC + Oracle 10g.  Here's my dataSource config:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" /> 
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="defaultRowPrefetch=1000" />
    </bean>
```

At first, I thought the connectionProperties value was being set but as I fine-tuned the query in SQL Developer (cost went from 3670 to 285 and plan explain went from :45 to :03), the time in the application never fluctuated from the original 15 seconds.  Removing the connectionProperties setting had no effect.  So, what I did was this:

DAO class

```
private List<Activity> getAllActivitiesJustJDBC() {
    String query = "select * " + "from activity a, work_order w "
            + "where a.ac_customer = 'CSC' "
            + "and w.wo_customer = a.ac_customer "
            + "and a.ac_workorder = w.wo_workorder ";
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    try {
        Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setFetchSize(1000);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        ActivityMapper mapper = new ActivityMapper();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Activity activity = mapper.mapRow(rs, 1);
            activities.add(activity);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Time it took...."
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    System.out.println("Number of activities = " + activities.size());
    return activities;
}
```

This time, the time it took to fetch 11,115 rows took on average 2 seconds.  The key statement is the setFetchSize(1000).  So....I like option #2 but do I need to close the connection or is Spring handling this for me?  In option #1, I would use the jdbcTemplate to call the query method, passing in the parameterized query and the BeanPropertyRowMapper instance using my data object and then returning the List.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from looking at other questions similar to this one, I do need to close out the connection starting with the result set, then statement, and then the connection using a finally.  I also remembered (from the days before Spring) I needed to wrap all that around a try/catch and then not really do anything if an exception occurs closing a connection.

FYI, I wonder if there's a way to set the fetch size when defining the datasource using Spring.

Here's the final method:

```
private List<Activity> getAllActivitiesJustJDBC() {
    String query = "select * " + "from activity a, work_order w "
            + "where a.ac_customer = 'CSC' "
            + "and w.wo_customer = a.ac_customer "
            + "and a.ac_workorder = w.wo_workorder ";
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setFetchSize(1000);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            activities.add(ActivityMapper.mapRow(rs));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            //Not much we can do here
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Time it took...."
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    System.out.println("Number of activities = " + activities.size());
    return activities;
}
```